# Python: slicing a list copy affects the original tuple or list when using nested for loops

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, slice

I'm having trouble changing any list copies of a list or tuple. When using two nested For loops the tuple is changed, as below:

```
testInput = ( ['foo','foo',], ['foo','foo'] )
testCopy = list(testInput)

for rowIndex, row in enumerate(testCopy):
    for columnIndex, column in enumerate(row):
        testCopy[rowIndex][columnIndex] = ['bar']

print(testInput)
print(testCopy)

>>>([['bar'], ['bar']], [['bar'], ['bar']])
>>>[[['bar'], ['bar']], [['bar'], ['bar']]]
```

when only using one for loop is used, it works as I expect it to and only changes the copy:

```
for rowIndex, row in enumerate(testCopy):
    testCopy[rowIndex] = ['bar']

>>>([['foo'], ['foo']], [['foo'], ['foo']])
>>>[['bar'], ['bar']]
```

this happens regardless of if the original is a list or tuple or however the copy is formatted:

```
testCopy = testInput
testCopy = list(testInput)
testCopy = testInput[:]
```

Comment: `testCopy = list(testInput)` is a shallow copy, and also sort of not a copy, because `testInput` was a tuple, not a list.

Comment: ah I understand. It's only copying the outer layer of the data, so `['data']` is a unique list referencing the non-unique `'data'`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Nested list copy with recursive function:**
This way the copy is a copy not related with the original

```
def copyList(yourList):   
    yourCopiedList=[]   
    for listElement in yourList:
    if type(listElement)==list:
      yourCopiedList.append(copyList(listElement.copy()))
    else:
      yourCopiedList.append(listElement)   
    return yourCopiedList
```

Comment: This is not really useful when there's the less restricted `copy.deepcopy`.

Comment: do not reinvent the wheel, there is a [`copy` module](https://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) with [`deepcopy` function](https://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

Comment: also `type(listElement)==list` is an anti-pattern, we have [`isinstance` built-in](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance)